# Putting multiple algorithm2e procedures in figure

Tags: algorithm2e

I want to put some `algorithm2e` procedures into a figure like:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{procedure}
some code \;
\caption{abc (n).}
\end{procedure}

\begin{procedure}
some code \;
\caption{abc (n).}
\end{procedure}

\caption{some procedures.}
\end{figure}
```

Please, how to do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Your welcome. You can use select the code and then hit the `{}` to format the code -- refer to [Markdown help](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for more detauls.  And keep in mind that while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and all the appropriate packages.  While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `procedure` environment like `algorithm` is already a float so you cannot place it inside `figure` or `table` directly. See this [discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26058/11241) for more details.

You can place your procedures in `minipage` environment  <s>and add caption using `captionof` command from `caption` package.</s>  and then enclose them in `figure` environment as follows,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{procedure}[H]
        some code \;
         \caption{abc (n).}
    \end{procedure}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{procedure}[H]
        some code \;
        \caption{abc (n).}
    \end{procedure}
    \end{minipage}
\caption{some procedures.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: code output]

You may also want to look at the answers for this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40365/place-four-algorithms-algorithm2e-in-a-subfigure-and-arrange-them-in-two-rows).