# How to reduce space below algorithm(s) without affecting other floats?

Tags: spacing, floats, algorithm2e

I'm using `algorithm2e` to layout algorithms.

I am looking for a way to reduce the space below an algorithm, without affecting figures that I have in the document.

For figures and their captions, as a quick fix I sometimes use `\vspace{}` with negative values, but I could not figure out how to use that for an algorithm.

There are solutions that suggest to adjust `\textfloatsep` (see addendum [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26057/squeezing-space-around-algorithm-construct)). However, as far as I understand, that affects all floats and I am not aware of a way to set this value for one float (the algorithm) separately.

Comment: Any updates? Does the problem still exists? If yes please add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.